# Mapper decorator not getting compiled

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, mapstruct

Mapper decorator for my mapper is not getting compiled.Mapper is getting compiled, but not the decorator. Because, during the build I'm getting the type conversion error, even though I'm doing it in the mapper decorator. Is there anything more to add?

mapper code:

```
 @Mapper
    @DecoratedWith(OneMapperDecorator.class)

    public interface OneMapper {
     public TwoObject convertToTwoObject(OneObject one);
    }
```

decorator code:

```
     public abstract class OneMapperDecorator implements OneMapper {

            private final OneMapper delegate;

            public OneMapperDecorator (OneMapper delegate) {
                this.delegate = delegate;
            }
            @Override
            public TwoObject convertToTwoObject(OneObject one)
            {
                TwoObject two=delegate.convertToTwoObject(one);

                two.setTotalFare(new BigDecimal(one.getPrice()));//string to bigdecimal conversion
                return two;
            }
}
```

Comment: *Is there anything more to add*, what actual Exception you get might help

Comment: Can't map property "java.lang.String price" to "java.math.BigDecimal fare". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.math.BigDecimal map(java.lang.String value)".

This is the error @Eugene

Comment: well isn't that a bit different from what you said : *Mapper decorator for my mapper is not getting compiled*? do you understand that it is entirely different now?

Comment: I have implemented the type conversion method in the decorator @Eugene...Then why the error??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decorator is meant to augment the mapping not to replace it. MapStruct has no way of knowing that you are mapping your `totalFare` in the decorator. You have 2 options:

#### Define a custom mapping method

In your `OneMapper` you can add a default method that would perform the mapping (as the error says.

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(OneMapperDecorator.class)
public interface OneMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "totalFare", source = "price");
    TwoObject convertToTwoObject(OneObject one);

    default BigDecimal map(String value) {
        return value == null ? null : new BigDecimal(value);
    }

}
```

#### Ignore the mapping

In case you want to do the mapping in your decorator then you need to tell MapStruct to not map it.

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(OneMapperDecorator.class)
public interface OneMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "totalFare", ignore = true);
    TwoObject convertToTwoObject(OneObject one);

}
```

---

One advise from me if you are using your delegate only to map extra fields I would either add custom methods or use `@AfterMapping` and `@BeforeMapping` to handle that.

Comment: Thank You.Your solution was perfect. Actually I had another field with same name but different data type...also needed string to Bigdecimal conversion.  But since that field had the same name in both bean classes...the mapping was happening in mapper itself... it was not proceeding to decorator... that is why I was getting compilation error. So I added ignore='true' as you mentioned.